# ZSH listing a dir with ls and assigning to var and then using a loop with far gives error about file not found on last file

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh

So I use ssh-add to add all my ssh keys in a certain directory

```
stuff=`ls *.prv`
for i in $stuff;do ssh-add $i;done
```

however, this doesnt work and it always seems to complain about the last file.

```
/stuff/github.prv
/stuff/github_2.prv: No such file or directory
```

when I add a new file
it becomes

```
/stuff/github.prv
/stuff/github_2.prv
/stuff/github_3.prv: No such file or directory
```

I've read that zsh appends a "%" when there is no newline, not sure if that is what's messing it up.

However this works perfectly fine in bash but doesnt seem to work in zsh.

And also, it seems that when it fails, ssh-add adds no keys

Comment: [Parsing `ls` is an antipattern](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- don't do it in zsh _or_ bash. `for i in *.prv; do ssh-add "$i"; done`; see also [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: To be clear, your immediate problem is that you're passing a string with all three filenames to `ssh-add` as if it were just one filename; but that's not the only problem `ls` has in this context, so you're very much better off not using it at all.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Comment: Charles Duffy is right, been doing it all wrong all these years!

Comment: now how do I select that as the answer

Comment: In bash, the output of the `ls` command (i.e. the content of the variable `stuff`) is broken up on white space, and the loop is executed for each of these pieces. In zsh, the loop is executed only once, with `i` having the full content of `stuff`. Reason is that bash is doing parameter expansion before word splitting, and zsh is doing word splitting before parameter expansion.